# Cypress error with cy.visit - response Content Type: utf-8

Tags: automation, cypress

i have a error with Cypress when used cy.visit('https://example.com'),

i got response error: charset=utf-8, and response must have, content-type: 'text/html'

It's possible solve?, where i don't access to code from website. Thanks

I tried, with others pages and load correctly, but con el website  particular not load with cy.visit

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't have access to the code of the website, there are limited options to directly solve this issue. The problem lies with the server configuration, which is beyond the control.

You can try the following and see if this helps :

Specify the content type: You can try specifying the expected content type explicitly in your Cypress test using the accept option. For example:

```
cy.request({
  url: 'https://example.com',
  headers: {
    accept: 'text/html',
  },
});
```

This will set the accept header in the request to indicate that the expected content type is 'text/html'.

Comment: Thanks, I think use cy.visit with headers, but i got error, in mi team contact con analyst system and he search error in code, in views html and  php , resuming in code php is defined header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8') , he comment it with //, and i can used cy.visit correctly.

Comment: Okay. Great to know that. Thank you